# UITableView reorderControl (or contentView) Width

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I use `UITableView` with variable cell heights. The table is always in editing mode (showing reorder controls).

The problem is that in order to calculate height of the cell in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, I need to know width of `contentView`. Alternatively it'd enough to know the width of reorder controls.

Is there a way to do it without getting it from undocumented subviews or using fixed size values?

Comment: can you get the cell from **cellForRowAtIndexPath** and get the height of the cell?

Comment: Nope. The cell doesn't exist yet. It's created after `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost a hack, but it should work. Knowing that the reorder accessory width is always 40px on all devices, the cell content width in edit mode should always be equal to:

```
CGFloat contentWidth = tableView.frame.size.width - 40.0f;
```

Comment: Yeah, if there's nothing better, I'm going to use that.

Comment: OK, ended up with a category on `UITableView` that defines `UITableViewCellReorderControlWidth` as a `CGFloat const`.